# Bash Script to replicate files

Tags: linux, bash

I have 25 files in a directory. I need to amass 25000 files for testing purposes. I thought I could just replicate these files over and over until I get 25000 files. I could manually copy paste 1000 times but that seemed tedious. So I thought I could write a script to do it for me. I tried

```
cp * .
```

As a trial but I got an error that said the source and destination file are the same. If I were to automate it how would i do it so that each of the 1000 times the new files are made with unique names?

Comment: I would do `for file in *; do for i in {1..10000}; do touch $file${i}; done; done`. This will copy every file 10.000 times by adding a suffix 1-10000.

Comment: how do i prevent the loop from executing on the newly created files?

Comment: you could just grab all the files in the directory initially in a variable and then start the for loop.

        files=`ls -S *`
        for myfile in $files

Comment: The `*` is expanded when `for` is invoked. You can test with for example: `touch a{0..25}` and then `for file in a*; do for i in {1..5}; do touch $file$i; done; done`. This will create 25 x 5 = 125 sample files.

Comment: @fedorqui you probably mean `for file in *; do for i in {1..1000}; do cp ${file}{,$i}; done; done` for `COPY` and not a simple touch. ;)

Comment: Wow Thanks @fedorqui, That Worked. But I have to preserve the extension of the created files :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can do something like this:

```
for file in *
do
   filename="${file%.*}"    # get everything up to last dot
   extension="${file##*.}"  # get extension (text after last dot)
   for i in {00001..10000}
   do
       cp $file ${filename}${i}${extension}
   done
done
```

The trick `for i in {00001..10000}` is used to loop from 1 to 10000 having the number with leading zeros.

The `${filename}${i}${extension}` is the same as `$filename$i$extension` but makes more clarity over what is a variable name and what is text. This way, you can also do `${filename}_${i}${extension}` to get files like `a_23.txt`, etc.

In case your current files match a specific pattern, you can always do `for file in a*` (if they all are on the `a` + `something` format).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the extension of the files, you can use this. Assuming, you want to copy all `txt`-files:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.txt
do
  for i in {1..10000}
  do
    cp "$f" "${f%.*}_${i}.${f##*.}"
  done
done
```

Comment: No need to `seq 1 1000`. As 1 is default, you can do `seq 1000` or directly `{1..1000}` so that you don't need to call an external command. Also, `$()` is preferred over backticks - this way you can nest them!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
for file in *; do for i in {1..1000}; do cp $file $file-$i; done; done;
```

It will append a number to any existing files.

Comment: you can write this also, as: `for file in *; do for i in {1..1000}; do cp ${file}{,$i}; done; done`

Answer (score 1):

The next script

```
for file in *.*
do
    eval $(sed 's/\(.*\)\.\([^\.]*\)$/base="\1";ext="\2";/' <<< "$file")
    for n in {1..1000}
    do
        echo cp "$file" "$base-$n.$ext"
    done
done
```

will:

- take all files with extensions `*.*`
- creates the basename and extension (`sed`)
- in a cycle 1000 times copyes the original file to file-number.extension
- it is for DRY-RUN, remove the echo if satisfied